# React reducer not being called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reduce

I have started learning React and redux and I created a simple login application using redux.

The reducer is not being called.
I get an error in console.

[image]

I tried to create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4tbkdu?file=src/components/Login.js) but react is not working in it.
The stackblitz has all the code same as my application.

Could somebody have a look and tell me my mistake.

Thanks
Shruti Nair

Comment: Use codesandbox.io instead of stackblitz. And it still helps to paste the problematic part of your code in the question.

Comment: Paste code here too

Comment: @dulaj's and Erfan's answers helped me.Its working now.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the reducer(slice) it should be **`reducers`** instead of **`reducer`**.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { login } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a typo but you are importing `login` as default inside `Login.jsx`:

```
import login from '../features/userSlice';
```

Should be:

```
import {login} from '../features/userSlice';
```

The other issue is using `reducer` instead of `reducers`, As the other answer points.